# Access to XMLHttpRequest at address from origin address has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, go, axios, cors

I have been trying to figure this out for the last 3 days why this does not work, when I send a request from a Vue Axios API call to the backend I get a CORS policy error below.

My App Stack:

- Golang (Gin)
- Vue
- PostgreSQL (Gorm)

I get the error in the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/admin/users' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have tried setting the header with `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'` with many different variations on the Vue side and Gin side:

Vue

```
 const apiClient = axios.create({
 baseURL: baseURL,
 withCredentials: false, // This is the default
 crossDomain: true,
 headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'
  // 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
 },
 timeout: 10000
 })
```

Gin:

```
r := gin.Default()

//config := cors.DefaultConfig()
//config.AllowOrigins = []string{"http://localhost:8000"}
//r.Use(cors.New(config))

r.Use(cors.Default())
```

But nothing works, it all started when I had to set withCredentials: true because I need to send the seesion to the backend.

I am starting to think maybe its because this users routes are in a private group or something but I doubt it:

```
// User routes
admin := r.Group("/admin")
admin.Use(controllers.AuthRequired)
{
    admin.GET("/users/", controllers.FindUsers)
    admin.GET("/users/:id", controllers.FindUser)
    admin.POST("/users", controllers.CreateUser)
    admin.PATCH("/users/:id", controllers.UpdateUser)
    admin.DELETE("/users/:id", controllers.DeleteUser)
}
```

Could anyone give me some other ideas I can try.

Comment: You need to start by removing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080` header from your frontend JavaScript code, and the using https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64112975/edit to edit/update the question to remove the error message about that, and replace that error message with whatever error message you get once you’ve removed that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080` part from your frontend code. That’s a response header, not a request header. You can’t fix anything by trying to send it as a request header.

Comment: Does the axios.create call cause a POST request to be sent, or a GET request? Are you sending some request body with data in the request? If not, then you can remove the entire `headers: {…}` block from that axios call — because you don’t need to add the Content-Type header if there’s no request body.

Comment: Thanks, I removed `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from JS, I get the same error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/admin/users' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` On the gin side tried as well `r.Use(cors.Default())` and `r.Use(cors.AllowAll())`  as suggested below. Also I do not want to remove the headers as I will be reusing this API client, this time I am sending GET without any body, but I will reuse it to POST as well.

Comment: And thanks for clarification, so the main issue here is that `gin` does not send back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header?

Comment: Yup, looks like it doesn't. At least I understand better where the issue lies now. Thnx will try to troubleshoot further

Answer (score 0):

have you tried github.com/rs/cors ?

I think you can use this on golang:
https://github.com/rs/cors/blob/master/examples/gin/server.go

example :

```
  import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    cors "github.com/rs/cors/wrapper/gin"
)

func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.AllowAll())
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "pong")
    })
    return r
}
```

if you use **r.Use(cors.Default())** you just open the GET and POST methods

hopefully can help..